# Magento admin Forgot password not triggering email

Tags: magento, admin, forgot-password

I am checking "Forgot Password" link in Magento 1.9.1 but when I click on Forgot Password and provide my email id, it is giving message reset link email will be sent to your email id.

But I am not receiving any email for admin forgot password. I am getting password reset link for Customers account.

Can you please help with this?

Regards,
Nilesh Bhayani

Answer (score 0):

if you install new them platform included your information probably change... I dont know which hosting u hired but all of them similar... 
Follow this steps

Hosting's Cpanel > Web Application > My Application

select your apllication (magento , wordpress , joomla etc.) and click edit.

You can see your admin name , password and mail information... you can change it what you want... Control mail section, change mail adress and try again